# How to change audio files of Radcaptcha in Dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, telerik, dotnetnuke, captcha

I use feedback 6.0.0 in my DNN site which use RadCaptcha with audio code.
when I use it in localhost it works fine and I can replace another .wav files with default audio files .but when I install this module on server, module reads audio files from WebResource not from address I set and I can't replace this audio files.

even I delete this audio files from RadCaptcha folder, this module reads audio files from webResource.

I use this code to use RadCaptcha:

```
 <dnn:dnnCaptcha ID="ctlCaptcha" runat="server" EnableRefreshImage="True" Width="300px" CaptchaImage-AudioFilesPath="~/DesktopModules/Feedback/App_Data/RadCaptcha" />
```

my question is how can i replace my custom audio files in RadCapcha in server not in localhost

Answer (score 1):

Atabrizi, have you configured the handler properly in the web.config file?

```
<httphandlers>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" /> 
</httphandlers>
<handlers>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" /> 
</handlers>
```

Also, I found the following piece of information in their documentation:

> In order for the Captcha to be able to output an audio file the web
>   application must be run in a full trust environment. Basically the
>   application should run as a user account that has permissions to call
>   the SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(textToSpeak) method on the server. Usually
>   the user account does not have the needed permissions and the
>   administrator has to grant them. For example in IIS 6+ the Application
>   Pools run as the ApplicationPoolIdentity built-in account (this is by
>   default) which does not have enough permissions to call
>   SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(textToSpeak). To be able to generate the code
>   the Application Pools should have permissions as the LocalSystem
>   built-in account.

However there is an alternative mentioned as well:

> In case the web application does not have enough permissions to
>   "Speak" the text code or it uses .NET2.x (earlier than 3.0 versions of
>   .NET Framework), the audio file will be generated by concatenation of
>   ".wav" files that correspond to the specific character from the text
>   code. By default RadCaptcha will look for the files in the
>   App_Data\RadCaptcha directory, so you need to supply the folder and
>   the files. You can copy the App_Data\RadCaptcha directory located in
>   the App_Data folder of your RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX installation.
>   Please note that in order for the audio code to be generated
>   correctly, there must be a ".wav" file for every possible character
>   that can appear on the image and the file must be named as the
>   character itself - "[Char]".wav (i.e. A.wav, B.wav, C.wav, 1.wav,
>   2.wav etc.).

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/captcha_audio.html

Comment: @atabrizi Did you get it working?  If you found my post helpful, please mark it as Accepted.  If not, let me know how I can help further.  Thanks!